# How to find the local maximum and minium points,as well as the interval of increase/decrease on the derivative equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, maximum

How to find the local maximum and minimum points, as well as the interval of increase/decrease on the derivative equation,x^6-10x^5-780^3+2500x^2

Answer (score 2):

There is only a minima at zero x

```
f = x^6 - 10 x^5 - 780^3 + 2500 x^2;
Plot[f, {x, -1, 1}]
df = D[f, x];
NSolve[df == 0, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 0}}

Comment: Why put the domain of -1 and 1

Comment: No reason. `Plot[f, {x, -10, 15}]` is perhaps more interesting.